# Google Hadoop Filesystem Encryption

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc, google-hadoop

In normal operation one can provide encryption keys to the google storage api to encrypt a given bucket/blob:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/customer-supplied-encryption

Is this possible for the output of spark/hadoop jobs  "on the fly"?

Say we wanted to encrypt the output of a spark write

```
 df.write().format("json").save("gs:///somebucket/output");
```

In https://storage.googleapis.com/hadoop-conf/gcs-core-default.xml there is no way to specify an encryption key.

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking if customer-supplied encryption keys are currently available on Cloud Dataproc, the answer is no. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/security/encryption-at-rest/) is a list of current products options for encryption at rest at Google.

If you were just looking to encrypt the output of a Spark write, you could still encrypt this at the application layer using Google's Cloud KMS. [Here's a codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-encrypt-with-kms/index.html) for doing so in Google Cloud Storage (which looks like what you're doing with the command above). *Note that customer content is encrypted at rest on Google cloud platform by default at the storage layer, so this is another layer of protection.*